# C functions before mainCRTStartup on Mingw?

Tags: c, startup, msvcrt

```
void start() {
stuff(); //code before mainCRTStartup
mainCRTStartup();
}
int main()
{
//other code
}
```

In Visual C++,it compiles fine and function "stuff()" gets called before main. How would call "stuff()" before "mainCRTStartup()"? on Mingw(OS:Windows NT)? it seems to ignore "void start()".

Comment: but why do you want to do this instead of putting the code in main - yes, I have done a similar thing... but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the -e argument to `ld` (the linker) to specify `start` as your entry point.

I'm not sure how to feed arguments to `ld` using mingw; perhaps someone can edit my answer to provide that.

Answer (score 0):

The real entry point is always `start()`.

`start()` calls `mainCRTStartup()` that initializes CRT functions and call `main()`, so in `stuff()`, you can not use CRT functions.

Comment: This is incorrect. On Windows, the default entry point symbol varies depending on the subsystem in use at link time but is always in a format similar to `mainCRTStartup`. `_start` as a linker entry point is purely a convention (I believe originating in gcc) and is not necessarily the entry point name on other platforms or even other linkers.