# GCC: compiling an application without linking any library

Tags: c, windows, gcc, libc

I know how to compile a C application without linking any library using GCC in bare metal embedded application just setting up the startup function(s) and eventually the assembly startup.s file.

Instead, I am not able to do the same thing in Windows (I am using MINGW32 GCC). Seems that linking with -nostdlib removes also everything needed to be executed before main, so I should write a specific startup but I did not find any doc about that.

The reason because I need to compile without C std lib is that I am writing a rduced C std lib for little 32 bits microcontrollers and I would like to test and unit test this library using GCC under Windows. So, if there is an alternative simplest way it is OK for me.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you trying to compile for Micro-controller ? if so you need to have supported toolchain package. May be you can you cygwin or mingw to cross compile for micro-controller

Comment: I already can compile for the microcontroller but it is more time consuming. I found a solution adding -nostdlib -lgcc switches to the linker but after that I am not able to debug using gdb, seems it does not stop on any breakpoint.

Comment: you mean run time debug with controller ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling without libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548486/compiling-without-libc)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948630/3545273) can help...

Comment: May [help](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/hello-from-a-libc-free-world-part-1)

Comment: @ntshetty. He means he wants to test the library implementation on a PC.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution adding -nostdlib and -lgcc together to ld (or gcc used as linker). In this way the C standard lib is not automatically linked to the application but everything needed to startup the application is linked.

I found also that the order of these switches matters, it may not work at all, signal missing at_exit() function or work without any error/warning depending by the order and position of the options.

I discovered another little complication using Eclipse based IDEs because there are some different approaches in the Settings menu so to write the options in the right order I needed to set them in different places.

After that I had a new problem: I did not think that unit test libraries require at least a function able to write to stdout or to a file.

I found that using "" and <> forces the compiler and linker to use the library modules I want by my library and the C standard library.

So, for instance:

```
#include "string.h" // points to my library include
#include <stdio.h>  // points to C stdlib include
```

permits me to test all my library string functions using the C stdlib stdout functions. 
It works both using GCC and GCC Cross Compilers.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer of *how to compile a c program without linking* in linux **(gcc/debian)** is using command "**gcc -c $CFILE**"

in case you don't understand this , execute this script

#!/usr/bin/bash
gcc -c $CFILE

then Export $CFILE to your c filename
example EXPORT

Comment: Not what he asked.  Compiling a file without linking does not result in an executable.